# Pascal / Inno Setup Language Changer - Button

Tags: button, inno-setup

I have a problem with Inno Setup. I want to create a button in my autorun but O don't know how. That button should change language. Is it possible?
I created few lines of code but it doesn't work ;/
Please help me if you can.
P.S. Sorry for my English. I still learn it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the langauge of an Inno Install once it has started and shown the wizard page.
If you want the user to choose the langauge, then use the standard dislaog that appears when the setup starts by setting `ShowLanguageDialog=yes`

Comment: So it isn't possible. I know about ShowLanguageDialog. Thanks for reponse.